# Adding boolean values in Scala

Tags: scala

I think Scala is the first language I've come across where the following doesn't work:

```
true + true
// Name: Compile Error
// Message: <console>:32: error: type mismatch;
//  found   : Boolean(true)
//  required: String
//        true + true
//               ^
// StackTrace:
```

Can someone explain this error? Why on earth are `String`s getting involved?

Also, what is the canonical way to accumulate `Boolean` values in Scala? Do I need to convert them to `Int` / is there a way to overload `+` for it to work as expected?

Comment: Per your last question ("is there a way to overload `+`") - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633719/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-a-boolean-to-an-integer

Comment: What is the intended behavior of "adding" booleans?

Comment: Tzach has already posted the SO question to look at which answers your question. you need BoolToInteger conversion with `import scala.language.implicitConversions`. - http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-conversions.html

Comment: _"I think Scala is the first language I've come across where the following doesn't work"_ . I doubt this works in any modern and strongly typed language out of the box (at least it doesn't in languages like Rust or Swift, apart from Scala). Booleans and numbers are just different types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason "String" is getting involved is the implicit conversion from Boolean to String which allows writing expressions like `"text " + true` (which evaluates to `text true`).

You can create a similar implicit conversions from `Boolean` to `Int`, as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2635527/5344058):

```
implicit def bool2int(b:Boolean) = if (b) 1 else 0
```

Do note that now you'll have two implicit conversions from Boolean, which might get a bit tricky:

```
// without bool2int implicit conversion:
scala> true + true
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Boolean(true)
 required: String
       true + true
            ^

// conversion to String works:
scala> true + " text"
res1: String = true text

scala> "text " + true
res2: String = text true

// now we add bool2int:
scala> implicit def bool2int(b:Boolean) = if (b) 1 else 0
bool2int: (b: Boolean)Int

// which makes this work:
scala> true + true
res3: Int = 2

// BUT! now this conversion will be picked up because Int has a `+` method:
scala> true + " text"
res4: String = 1 text // probably not what we intended!

// This would still work as before:
scala> "text " + true
res5: String = text true
```

Comment: To be more precise, `"text " + true` doesn't need the conversion, `true + " text"` does.

Answer (score 1):

You can use implicit conversions. When the compiler find the expression is of wrong type, it will look for an implicit function. 
On creating the implicit function, the compiler will call it each time when Boolean is found but Int is required in the context.

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions
implicit def toInt(v:Boolean):Int = if (v) 1 else 0
```

To see how it works, let's add a print statement

```
implicit def toInt(v:Boolean):Int = {
 println (s"Value: $v")
 if (v) 1 else 0
}
```

Output:

```
scala> val x = false
x: Boolean = false

scala> val y = true
y: Boolean = true

scala> x
res6: Boolean = false // No implicit function called.

scala> x + y
Value: false // Implicit function called for x.
Value: true  // Implicit function called for y.
res5: Int = 1
```

So this function is called when Boolean is found and Int is required in the context, but not otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to implicit conversion, you can also convert the boolean to a wrapped type which supplies an addition operator.

```
class WrappedBoolean(bool: Boolean) {
    val value = if (bool) 1 else 0

    def +(other: Boolean) = (if (other) 1 else 0) + value
}  

implicit def boolean2WrappedBoolean(bool: Boolean) = new WrappedBoolean(bool)
```